# How to use uint64_t data type for ARM 32 bit architecture( Arm Cortex-A15 / Arm Cortex-M4)

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, processor

With yocto project, I have developed an application for 64 bit x86_64 architecture and the application is using uint64_t data type inside code. The application was compiling successfully for x86_64 architecture.

The same application when i try tp port to Arm Cortex-A15 / Arm Cortex-M4 architecture , the application was not compiling and below error observed during compilation process.  Please share if anyone knows solution for this issue.

{standard input}: Assembler messages:

{standard input}:2478: Error: bad instruction `lock'

{standard input}:2479: Error: bad instruction `xadd r3,[r4,#8]'

{standard input}: Assembler messages:

{standard input}:1794: Error: bad instruction `lock'

const uint64_t MAX_TRANSFER_BYTES = omniORB::giopMaxMsgSize();

> Processor:    TI AM5716, TI AM5726, TI AM5728, TI AM5748, TI AM5749

> Architecture:     Arm Cortex-A15 / Arm Cortex-M4

Thanks,

Punnarao

Comment: Please help if anyone knows a solution for the reorted issue..

Comment: Are you compiling for arm A15 or M4?

Comment: is your application you wrote using any inline assembly?

Comment: Or more likely omniORB  are uses in line assembly. Search though the source for "xadd", and it migh be uses in a semaphore.